# Changing group and retaining environment variables

Tags: permissions, environment-variables, tcsh

On campus, everyone's primary group is `user` and each person is additionally associated to groups depending on the courses he or she is taking, lab he or she works at, etc.

My coworker and I are members of group `foo`, so we use `newgrp foo` and `umask 7` to ensure our files are accessible to the two of us without granting *everyone* permission. Neither of us minded this.

However, we now need our `PATH` environment variable to first point to our lab's `bin` folder before the rest in the `PATH`. We thought a simple script would work, but it doesn't as the `PATH`'s contents don't persist after executing `newgrp`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
setenv PATH "/path/to/lab/bin:$PATH"
newgrp foo
```

The default shell is `tcsh`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using? What network filesystems (NFS, AFS, …), if any? Are access control lists (ACLs) available? Are you willing to change your work habits a little (e.g. use `chgrp` more and `newgrp` less) if it turns out to be possible?

Comment: CentOS 5.4. Our project is stored locally on the server. We are using Python with custom modules and hence why we want the Python in our `bin` ran before the system's. And yes, we are willing to change work habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need to type a password when you run `newgrp` (a very rarely used feature), you don't need to use `newgrp` to make files owned by the appropriate group. You can use `chmod` instead. For example, instead of the following workflow:

```
newgrp lab1
mkdir project1
$EDITOR project1/file1
```

you can do this:

```
mkdir project1
chgrp lab1 project1
$EDITOR project1/file1
chgrp lab1 project1/file1
```

On most current unices, either `project1/file1` will already belong to `lab1` like the directory it contains (*BSD), or you can force this behavior (Linux, Solaris, …):

```
mkdir project1
chgrp lab1 project1
chmod g+s project1
$EDITOR project1/file1
```

All of this requires that your `umask` be set to 002 or 007.

---

It's easier to manage permissions if [access control lists (ACL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) are supported. ACL support must be present in the disk filesystem driver and enabled in the mount options, and again for the network filesystem if applicable. ACLs support is not yet generalized, so you might not have it.

To see if you can use ACLs, on a Linux client, try running

```
touch foo
setfacl -m user:myfriend:rwx foo
ls -l foo
```

If the permissions of `foo` show up as `-rw-rw-r--+` or similar (with a `+` at the end), ACLs are enabled. If the `setfacl` utility isn't available, then your campus network probably doesn't have ACLs all around.

If you do have ACLs, then you don't need to have a permissive umask, you can stick with 022 or 077. With ACLs, to set up a group-writable directory (where newly created files will be writable by the group as well), do

```
mkdir project1
setfacl -m group:lab1:rwx project1; setfacl -d -m group:lab1:rwx project1
```

In addition to not requiring a permissive umask, ACLs let you share files between an arbitrary set of users and groups.

Comment: Thanks! ACLs are not set up, but `chmod g+s` did the trick!